# android - Don't want show the spinner dropdown if it is empty

Tags: android, android-spinner

I don't want to show the spinner drop down if it is empty. I tried but i am not getting please can anyone help me.

code:

```
sp.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //narray is the array. It's having the elements of spinner.
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && narray.size() == 0) {
            sp.setPressed(false);
            sp.setSelected(false);
            sp.setAdapter(null);
        }
        return false;
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this in your code to check array size is <= 0

```
String[] b = {};

    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            if (b.length <= 0) {
                spin.setClickable(false);
            }
```

try this code spinner not open.

Edited :

do like below

```
    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    spin.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (b.length <= 0) {
            spin.setClickable(false);
            Toast.makeText(StackoneActivity.this,
                    "spinner have no items", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: but here i want to show some message if we taps on the spinner.

Comment: check my edited ans.. one more thing please explain your all requirement in question before post que.

Comment: tell me one thing you have array to show spinner item?? if yes then array have 0 item then also spinner have 0 item.

Comment: your problem is solved its show you massage as well as its do't show you drop down..

Comment: but here spinner is not allow you to tap on second time. because we set it to non-clickable.

Comment: @naresh we need to return true in onTouch method .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if(narray.size() >= 0)
sp.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
        sp.setPressed(false);
        sp.setSelected(false);
        sp.setAdapter(null);
    }
    return false;
}       
});
```